# Displaying Powershell property with XML data as standard property output

Tags: xml, powershell, active-directory, attributes

I'm consuming a script written by someone else and it has some code I do not understand.  They are parsing the attribute **msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData** from an ADObject that contains XML data, but they are using a function I cannot seem to grasp.

Take the following code:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'samAccountName -eq <mysamAccountName>' -properties msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData |`
 select -ExpandProperty msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData
```

This results in the following (partial) output:

```
<DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA>
        <pszAttributeName>msTSLicenseVersion3</pszAttributeName>
        <dwVersion>1</dwVersion>
        <ftimeLastOriginatingChange>2022-02-16T21:11:07Z</ftimeLastOriginatingChange>
        <uuidLastOriginatingDsaInvocationID>520cec87-2f0e-44b1-b375-56d0dfe47886</uuidLastOriginatingDsaInvocationID>
        <usnOriginatingChange>9757364</usnOriginatingChange>
        <usnLocalChange>486069064</usnLocalChange>
        <pszLastOriginatingDsaDN></pszLastOriginatingDsaDN>
</DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA>
...
```

The question comes in with a modification to the above code as follows:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'samAccountName -eq <mysamAccountName>' -properties msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData |`
 select -ExpandProperty msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData |`
 foreach {([XML]$_.Replace("`0","")).DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA}
```

Leading to the following alternate output:

```
pszAttributeName                   : msTSLicenseVersion3
dwVersion                          : 1
ftimeLastOriginatingChange         : 2022-02-16T21:11:07Z
uuidLastOriginatingDsaInvocationID : 520cec87-2f0e-44b1-b375-56d0dfe47886
usnOriginatingChange               : 9757364
usnLocalChange                     : 486069064
pszLastOriginatingDsaDN            :
...
```

Now I understand **what** it's doing.  It's casting the property to XML and then iterating through each element named **DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA** and pulling the sub elements/properties.  **I just don't understand how** it's converting the results to standard property output.

**Specifically**, what exactly is the **replace** method replacing?  What does **"`0"** represent here that needs replacing with an **empty** string?

In an attempt to view the data without the replace method to try to decipher myself what is happening, it displays as standard xml, but also has some errors.  So clearly the replace method is what is transforming the output to standard property output, but how?

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'samAccountName -eq <mysamAccountName>' -properties msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData |`
 select -ExpandProperty msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData |`
 foreach {([XML]$_).DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA}

InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "<DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA>
        <pszAttributeName>msTSLicenseVersion3</pszAttributeName>
        <dwVersion>1</dwVersion>
        <ftimeLastOriginatingChange>2022-02-16T21:11:07Z</ftimeLastOriginatingChange>
        <uuidLastOriginatingDsaInvocationID>520cec87-2f0e-44b1-b375-56d0dfe47886</uuidLastOriginatingDsaInvocationID>
        <usnOriginatingChange>9757364</usnOriginatingChange>
        <usnLocalChange>486069064</usnLocalChange>
        <pszLastOriginatingDsaDN></pszLastOriginatingDsaDN>
</DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA>
" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 10, position 1."
...
```

**EDIT**

I happened upon another example online that does this differently, which kind of makes more sense to me, but still not fully understanding.

```
 $fu = $ds.findone()
 $xml = "" + $fu.properties."msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData" + ""
 $xml = [xml]$xml
 $xml.root.DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA |`
  select-object @{name="Attribute";expression={$_.pszAttributeName}},@{name="ChangeTime";expression={$_.ftimeLastOriginatingChange}}|
  Sort-Object attribute
```

In this case, I don't understand why we are adding an empty string before and after the attribute, but this is likely what the first example is also doing.  I'm also not sure why **root** is being specified in this one.  Granted this code is being extrapolated from an LDAP directory searcher object vs native Get-ADObject object.

Comment: `-Filter 'samAccountName=<mysamAccountName>'` is wrong because `=` is an assignment. Should be `-Filter "samAccountName -eq '<mysamAccountName>'"`

Comment: You are correct.  This was just a typo as I wrote this topic.  It is correct in the code, as evidenced by the provided results of running said code.